# Sort by price in html using Javascript?

Tags: arrays, sorting, items, price

I am trying to sort the items in my website by high/low price.  I can get the results to display in the console, sorted nicely, but how do I get them to update on the webpage?

http://jsfiddle.net/AQFFq/21/

```
function myFunction() {
var elements = [].slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName("price"));
elements.sort(function(a, b) {
return parseFloat(b.innerHTML.substring(1)) - parseFloat(a.innerHTML.substring(1));
});
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++)
elements[i].parentNode.appendChild(elements[i]);
console.log(elements);
}
```